# TNumberBox behavior changed from Delphi XE5 to XE6

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

In XE5 the Number Box could be totally cleared by using the Back Space button. In XE6 this behavior has changed so that the Back Space button no longer clears the entire Edit Box but leaves the last number to be deleted (which is the Min property value). This behavior makes it more difficult to enter values. Is there a way to revert back to the XE5 behavior?

Example:

Place a TNumberBox on a mobile form and set Min property to 18 and the Max property to 65.
Run the program and try to change the value to 25 using only the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (amateurish):-

Set the NumberBox Min property to 0 instead of 18, Max property to 65 and define the following OnChangeTracking event.

```
procedure TForm1.NumberBox1ChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
if Length(NumberBox1.Text)=NumberBox1.DecimalDigits then
  if NumberBox1.Text<'18' then
     NumberBox1.Text:='18';
end;
```